# Как изменить расстояние между кнопкой "назад" и заголовком в Toolbar

Tags: android, xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/icon_color"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:titleMargins="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            android:elevation="0dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_filter" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Какой кнопкой? Где тут кнопка? Может таки `app:titleMargins="16dp"` попробовать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб моё упущение) Кнопкой "назад"